If condemned men suffer forever in hell then why did Jesus say God destroys the body and soul in hell?
Saint John spoke under the influence of the Holy Spirit and wrote the following words that have echoed through the millenia.
John 3:16

For God so loved the world that he gave his only begotten Son, that whoever believes in him should not perish but have everlasting life

Those words mean that God has given the human race two options:-

Accept Jesus and live forever
Reject Jesus and perish

My focus is on the word perish, it means destruction, which suggests the meaning that unbelievers and sinners will ultimately be destroyed in hell.
Jesus supported this belief with this statement.
Mathew 10:28

Do not be afraid of those who kill the body but cannot kill the soul. Rather, be afraid of the One who can destroy both soul and body in hell.

That implies that the flesh and the inner man or the soul will both be destroyed in the lake of fire and that there is no eternal suffering for condemned men save for the devil and his angels, for God is just. The measurement for punishing eternal beings is not equal to the measurement for punishing mortal beings, why is it then that some men suffer forever when scripture is clearly opposed to that belief?

This question is answered under the previous question What-is-the-biblical-basis-for-the-eternal-existence-of-the-lost-in-hell?.
